# Qlik - Add month to date

Tags: loops, date, qliksense

I'm new to Qlik loops

I need to create dates until 2024.
I have the following data:
[image]

The Date column is a date that I retrieve from my database
The Periodicity column (these are months). This column I retrieve directly from my database.

Column Date 1 and Date 2 are columns I need to calculate in Qlik.

I want to loop to calculate these two columns, and the calculations are as follows:
**Example for PN 10101, Date: 01/02/2022, Periodicity = 12**

- **Date_1** = AddMonths(Date,periodicity) ----> **01/02/2023**
- **Date_2** = AddMonths(Date_1,periodicity) -----> **01/02/2024**

I only want to have 2 dates by PN (One date in 2023 and another in 2024). I don't want to generate multiple dates until 2024.

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop in this case.

```
DataBaseData:
Load
  PN,
  Date,
  // Define Date_1
  AddMonths(Date,Periodicity) as Date_1,
  // Wrap AddMonths into another AddMonths to get the second field
  AddMonths(Date,AddMonths(Date,Periodicity), Periodicity) as Date_2,
  Periodicity
From
  [some-database]
;
```

The other approach is to use [Preceding LOAD](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/preceding-load.htm) feature.

TLDR; Preceding load allows you to have nested loads that results in one table. Each preceding load takes the inner load result as an input.

```
DataBaseData:
// In the second step use the already available Date_1
// field and calculate Date_2
// * - will load all fields from the previous table
Load
  *,
  AddMonths(Date_1,Periodicity) as Date_2,
;
// In the first step calculate Date_1 fiels
Load
  PN,
  Date,
  AddMonths(Date,Periodicity) as Date_1,
  Periodicity
From
  [some-database]
;
```

P.S. The order of loading/executing, in the case of preceding load, is from bottom to top